# Spark performing much better than Drill with parquet tables

Tags: apache-spark, apache-drill

I am wondering what's your experience when you run SQL complex queries with multiple joins on parquet tables (few GBs to 2TBs) on Spark (2.2.1) and Drill (v.1.14).

My Drill cluster is as follow:

Direct_Memory : 42GB

num of drillbits : 10

Heap memory: 8GB

Cores on each drillbit: 8

I run tests on equivalent Spark cluster (in terms of resources). And I am finding that Spark is much faster than Drill. Also Drill occasionally is failing during execution with some more complex queries (which have for example SKEW in the data), whereas Spark can handle them easily.

Comment: I recommend you to use the last version of Drill - 1.15.0. It has improvements in pruning data in the process of query execution.
Also what answer do you expect? It is more like a discussion. So it may be better to write on drill user and dev mailing lists and to discuss there the failures, which you have faced:
https://drill.apache.org/mailinglists/

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the mailing list, will try there. Also will try with 1.15. The answer was expecting if someone else encountered similar issues with Drill, that basically is not handling very well complex SQL queries on large parquet tables.

Comment: Please feel free to create a Jira ticket with your observations and please provide all related details (CTAS, queries, logs, profiles etc.). It will be a good step to have some comparison with Spark and to fix an issue, if it exists.